# Java Recursive function fails

Tags: java, recursion, jgraph

My function is:

```
private void addEdges(mxICell mainObject, List<Object> edgesList) {
        if (mainObject.getEdgeCount() > 0) {
            // for (int i = 0; i < mainObject.getEdgeCount(); i++) {
            edgesList.add(mainObject.getEdgeAt(0));
            addEdges(((Line) mainObject.getEdgeAt(0)).getSource(), edgesList);
        }
        // }
        else
            return;
    }
```

**BEGING UPDATE**
The function calling is here:

```
for (Object obj : map.values()) {
                if (obj instanceof Port
                        && ((Port) obj).getParent().getStyle().equals("POWER")) {

                    String Feeder = ((Port) obj).getParent().getValue()
                            .toString();

                    List<Object> edgesList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                    Port p = (Port) obj;

                    mxICell mainObject = p;

                    addEdges(mainObject, edgesList);
//staff
}}
```

**END UPDATE**
it gives me a

```
 Exception occurred during event dispatching:
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Comment: Is the `edgeCount` affected by anything that you do within the loop?  If not, `Stack Overflow` is inevitable.

Comment: `mainObject.getEdgeCount()` is always `> 0`.

Comment: Please use some termination condition.

Comment: it seems that `mainObject.getEdgeCount()` is always > 0 but not

Comment: You've to use a condition where your Recursive function must end like mainObject.getEdgeCount() > 0  or == 0, otherwise it can fill your stack that causes "StackOverflowError"

Answer (score 2):

This is because once the edge count of your `mainObject` is greater than zero the function calls itself over and over again, resulting in a stackoverflow exception. You need to define a proper termination condition.

There is most likely a circle in your datastructure.

For example:

```
mainObject1.getEdgeAt(0).source == mainObject2
mainObject2.getEdgeAt(0).source == mainObject1
```

Or something like that. Fact is, your recursive call never terminates.

Comment: How is that possible? Recursive call is made on the next object which in this case is ((Line) mainObject.getEdgeAt(0)).getSource().

Comment: well we do not see the implementation, so the only logical conclusion is that you pass `mxICell` objects with edgecount greater than zero. maybe there is a circle in there too

Answer (score 1):

As you shown that in commented for loop that you are looping through all the getedge in the mainobject same way you have to reduce the edges from the main object too in case of recursive call. You have to reduce the edge which is already processed in the flow so that when you reach next level one edge is gone.

And also you have to make sure that then you are doing getsource for Line object it will some how reach the level where there are no more edges to process so that your termination condition works correctly.

Comment: if you look closely you will see that the for-loop is commented out. but you are still right, the edge count is never (most likely, as far as we can tell) zero between recursive calls

Comment: effectively i am not for-looping, but is there any explaination why `mainObject.getEdgeCount()` is alway `>0`!

Comment: That you have to answer @HoussemBdr as it is you code. If you want to know that then please add the mainObject code also.